# Why is valgrind reporting uninitialized values in my polymorphic type?

Tags: arrays, memory, fortran, polymorphism, gfortran

I recently stumbled across odd behaviour in my code where when modifying data-members of a polymorphic user defined type, the values of other data-members were changed.  I tried applying Valgrind to unravel what clearly seemed like a memory-related bug, and found several errors: `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)`

Upon further investigation, polymorphic data members are returning this error, even when they have been *explicitly* initialized just prior.  When I reference indices in the beginning of the allocated array `var(1)`, or implicitly index the array with `var(:)`, there are no problems, but explicitly referencing elements near the end of the array returns the Valgrind error.  For example:

```
module particles
  implicit none
  private

  public :: particleArray,initParticles,&
            FULLY_KINETIC,DRIFT_KINETIC

  integer,parameter :: &
    FULLY_KINETIC=1,&
    DRIFT_KINETIC=2

  type particle
    real :: x   ! position
  end type particle

  type, extends (particle) :: particle_dk
    real :: vpara ! parallel velocity
  end type particle_dk

  type, extends (particle) :: particle_fk
    real :: vx,vy ! x,y velocity
  end type particle_fk

  type particleArray
    private
    class(particle),dimension(:),allocatable :: p
  end type

  contains
    subroutine initParticles(pArray,iParticleType)
      type(particleArray),intent(out),target :: pArray
      integer,intent(in) :: iParticleType ! flag for FK vs. DK particles
      integer :: i,nparticles

      nparticles=10

      select case (iParticleType)
        case (FULLY_KINETIC)
          write(*,*)'   Particles are FULLY KINETIC.'
          allocate(particle_fk::pArray%p(nparticles))
        case (DRIFT_KINETIC)
          write(*,*)'   Particles are DRIFT KINETIC.'
          allocate(particle_dk::pArray%p(nparticles))
        case default
          write(*,*)'ERROR: Requested iParticleType not found.'
          stop
      end select

      ! initialize ALL particle array values
      pArray%p(:)%x = 0.0
      select type (pa => pArray%p)
        class is (particle_dk)
          pa(:)%vpara = 0.0
        class is (particle_fk)
          pa(:)%vx = 0.0
          pa(:)%vy = 0.0
      end select

      ! modify initialized value
      ! low indices are fine
      pArray%p(1:4)%x = max(pArray%p(1:4)%x,1.0e-6)

      ! so is this!
      pArray%p(:)%x = max(pArray%p(:)%x,1.0e-6)

      ! ERROR HERE
      ! but explicit indices near end of allocated array cause
      ! 'uninitialized' error in valgrind
      pArray%p(nparticles)%x = max(pArray%p(nparticles)%x,1.0e-6)

    end subroutine initParticles
end module particles

program test
  use particles

  type(particleArray) :: ions_dk,ions_fk

  call initParticles(ions_dk,DRIFT_KINETIC)
  call initParticles(ions_fk,FULLY_KINETIC)

end program test
```

Valgrind returns...

```
oghma@laptop:~/memory_bug> valgrind ./test
==16108== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16108== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16108== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16108== Command: ./test
==16108==
--16108-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./test"
    Particles are DRIFT KINETIC.
==16108== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16108==    at 0x100001B8B: __particles_MOD_initparticles (particles.F90:69)
==16108==    by 0x100000FE9: MAIN__ (main.F90:6)
==16108==    by 0x100001035: main (main.F90:2)
==16108==
    Particles are FULLY KINETIC.
==16108== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16108==    at 0x100001B8B: __particles_MOD_initparticles (particles.F90:69)
==16108==    by 0x100000FFC: MAIN__ (main.F90:7)
==16108==    by 0x100001035: main (main.F90:2)
==16108==
==16108==
==16108== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16108==     in use at exit: 22,223 bytes in 191 blocks
==16108==   total heap usage: 280 allocs, 89 frees, 34,316 bytes allocated
==16108==
==16108== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16108==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16108==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16108==      possibly lost: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
==16108==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 2 blocks
==16108==         suppressed: 19,959 bytes in 188 blocks
==16108== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==16108==
==16108== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16108== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==16108== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems like there is some sort of mismatch between expected size per item in `pArray%p` when allocated with `nparticles` and later when referenced with `nparticles`.  My allocation statements of the form   `allocate(particle_fk::pArray%p(nparticles))` are based on [IBM compiler documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2MB5_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/alloc.html) since I could not find the same for gfortran, that I am using to compile.  Am I allocating/referencing incorrectly, or is this a Fortran 2003 feature that is not correctly implemented in GCC?

Comment: This looks like some bogus warning. Sanitizations don't find anything and your code looks OK. I would just use `p%` instead of `p(:)%` but that is a style thing.

Comment: Would be worth trying more versions of GCC. Which version are you actually using?

Comment: If I initialize pArray% p(:)% x, para, vx, vy with, say 1, 10, 20, 30, and print the contents later, gfortran-6.1 and ifort16 give different results... hmm (but my modification may be wrong).

Comment: There were some bugs in gfortran fixed recently, but I think they concerned unlimited polymorphics. But it can be a bug in GCC. But one needs more than just a valgrind complaint.

Comment: In my actual code, the particle types have several more data members.  Setting a data member `p%weight` of the `particle` base type changes some but not all already-initialized values of `p%vx` and `p%vy` of the `particle_fk` type.

Comment: If I recompile this same source code with `ifort -g -O0 -c ...` then valgrind returns no errors, and the issue does not occur, using ifort version 15.0.0.

Comment: And getting the Valgrind errors when using GCC version 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simpler version of OP's program with different initial values for x etc (1,2,3,4).

```
module particle_mod
    implicit none

    type particle
        real :: x
    endtype

    type, extends(particle) :: particle_1
        real :: vp
    endtype

    type, extends(particle) :: particle_2
        real :: vx,vy
    endtype

    type particleArray
        class(particle), allocatable :: p(:)
    endtype

contains
    subroutine initParticles( pArray, itype )
      type(particleArray), intent(out) :: pArray
      integer, intent(in) :: itype
      integer :: nparticles
      character(20) :: fmt

      nparticles = 6

      select case ( itype )
        case ( 1 )
            print "(/,a)", "allocating type 1"
            allocate( particle_1 :: pArray % p( nparticles ) )
        case ( 2 )
            print "(/,a)", "allocating type 2"
            allocate( particle_2 :: pArray % p( nparticles ) )
      end select

      ! initialize all values
      pArray % p(:) % x = 1.0

      select type ( pa => pArray % p )
      class is ( particle_1 )
          pa(:) % vp = 2.0
      class is ( particle_2 )
          pa(:) % vx = 3.0
          pa(:) % vy = 4.0
      end select

      ! print the values
      fmt = "(a, *(f5.1, x))"
      print fmt, "x = ", pArray % p(:) % x

      select type ( pa => pArray % p )
      class is ( particle_1 )
          print fmt, "type1 : x  = ", pa(:) % x
          print fmt, "type1 : vp = ", pa(:) % vp
      class is ( particle_2 )
          print fmt, "type2 : x  = ", pa(:) % x
          print fmt, "type2 : vx = ", pa(:) % vx
          print fmt, "type2 : vy = ", pa(:) % vy
      end select

    end subroutine
end module

program test
    use particle_mod
    implicit none
    type(particleArray) :: ions_1, ions_2

    call initParticles( ions_1, 1 )
    call initParticles( ions_2, 2 )
end program
```

Then, if this program is compiled with gfortran-6.1, it gives the following result:

```
allocating type 1
x =   1.0   2.0   1.0   2.0   1.0   2.0
type1 : x  =   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
type1 : vp =   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0

allocating type 2
x =   1.0   3.0   4.0   1.0   3.0   4.0
type2 : x  =   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
type2 : vx =   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
type2 : vy =   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0   4.0
```

But the output of x(:) seems strange... (I expected it to give `1.0 1.0 ... 1.0`). I cannot access ifort right now, so it might be useful to try this program also with ifort.

Comment: I'm not very sure if the above program is correct, so I would appreciate it if you find a strange point..

Comment: It seems that when `pArray%p(:)%x` is accessed outside of a `select type` block, the memory is incorrectly accessed as if the inherited variables do not exist, i.e. `pArray%p` is being treated as a type as opposed to a class.

Comment: [Now I got access to ifort and oracle fortran etc, I will try similar patterns if they give the same or different results (depending on compilers) and check the syntax also. I'm still not very clear with this kind of syntactic behavior...]